# Помощь в Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Помогите пожалуйста,как в tkinter после ввода определенного слова сделать так, что бы выполнялось действие.К примеру  меня просят ввести имя(в виджет entry) если я ввожу Павел(именно Павел),то мне выдается сообщение:"У вас счастливое имя".
Заранее благодарю!

```
 window = Tk()
    window.geometry('850x500+500+150')
    entry=Label(width=84,bg='red')
    entry.place(x=125,y=400,height=50)
    entry1=Entry(width=20)
    entry1.place(x=358,y=410,height=35)
    font=("Arial Bold", 28)
    l='Напишите 'Павел
    label_2=Label(font=font,text=l)
    label_2.place(x=380,y=190)
    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно ещё таким образом сделать:

```
yes = 'счастливое'
no = 'не счастливое'
names = {'Павел':yes, "Ульяна":yes, "Алексей":no}
a = ent.get()
if a in names:
    la = Label(text='У вас {} имя'.format(names[a]))
    la.place(x= ,y= )
else:
    la = Label(text='Вас нет в базе данных')
    la.place(x= ,y= )
```

Но это для большего кол-ва имён

Comment: что это за команда ent.get()

Comment: @peter, `ent` - `Entry` откуда хотите данные взять, а `.get()` - получение введённых данных

Answer (score 3):

елси нужно сделать такое на некоторые имена, то можна сделать так:

```
a = ent.get()
if a == 'Павел':
    la = Label(text='У вас счастливое имя')
    la.place(x= ,y= )
```

такой метод подойте на одно два имя, если он вам подходит, используйте